# 特殊文字を検索する場合の演算子が正常に機能していない

Tags: バグ, 完了, ヘルプ, 検索

### 経緯

ヘルプセンターの「検索の方法は？」という記事に、特定のフレーズを検索する場合、または特殊文字の文字列を検索する場合の記法が以下のように記述されています<sup>[[1]](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/searching)</sup>。

> ### 検索の方法は？ <sup>[[1]](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/searching)</sup>
>
> - 特定のフレーズを検索する場合、または特殊文字の文字列を検索する場合は、`「パンク」`、または `"<%#"` のように、引用符の中に入力します。

これより、特殊文字の検索がダブルクォーテーションにより行えると思いました。

---

### 不具合事象

しかし、ビットシフト演算子 `>>` の記号で検索を行ったところ、[検索結果は 0 件](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22%3E%3E%22)でした。実際には、 `>>` に一致する内容が記述されている投稿は、 [`ビットシフト` で検索](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%E3%83%93%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%E3%82%B7%E3%83%95%E3%83%88)したところ、幾つか得られました。このことから、ヘルプセンターに記載されている `"<%#"` も同様に機能していないのではないかと思います。

検索フォームから特殊文字の検索が行える方法はありますか？また、もし引用符を用いた特殊文字の検索が行えないのであれば、ヘルプセンターの内容を変更する必要があると思います。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

これは仕様と思われ、ヘルプの原文から無くなっています。翻訳も原文に追随しました。

[ヘルプセンターの「検索の方法は？」を改善したい](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3957/3054)